# UIView's height depending on the height of the UIWebView inside

Tags: uiview, uiwebview

I currently have a UIScrollView with multiple UIView inside. And inside each UIView I want to put a UIWebView. The height of each UIWebView is set dynamically depending on the content. How could I do now to set the height of each UIView depending on the size of UIWebView ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
  uiView.frame = CGRectMake(desiredX, desiredY, desiredWidth, uiWebView.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use auto-layout and align the bottom of the UIWebView with the UIView.

```
[uiView alignBottomEdgeWithView:uiWebView predicate:@"10"];
```

Example: http://code.dblock.org/ios-uiview-with-an-image-and-text-with-dynamic-height